# How can I solve this issue, The argument type 'MaterialApp Function()' can't be assigned error

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using ScreenUtilInit and this error is occurred,

```
The argument type 'MaterialApp Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, Widget?)',
```

This is the flutter code segment, and how can I solve this issue

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return ScreenUtilInit(
      designSize: const Size(375, 812),
      builder: (){
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter E-Commerce',
          theme: ThemeData(  
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          ),
          home: SplashScreen(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please format your code correctly and don't just post an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The builder of ScreenUtilInit requires Build context and an optional Widget parameter.

```
   class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    
      static const double _designWidth = 375;
      static const double _designHeight = 812;
      const MyApp(Key? key}) : super(key: key);
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return ScreenUtilInit(
          designSize: const Size(_designWidth, _designHeight),
          builder: (context, widget) => MaterialApp(
            theme: ThemeData(useMaterial3: true),
            title:"Flutter E-Commerce",
            home: const SplashScreen(),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```